# Close React Native apps / dispatch redux action when running on background

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to create a function inside my components that detect when the app is in the background for 30 seconds, I want to dispatch a logout action or close the apps. is that possible if we do that in react native?

I'm using hooks

Thanks,

update :
I'm using the wowandy's solution but the thing is if user close the apps for less than 10 seconds and then open the app again, the dispatch command will still be executed in 30 seconds. is there any way to cancel the timeout ?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;

    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState) => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);


      if (appState.current === 'background') {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => dispatch(removeDataLogin()), 30000);
      }

      appState.current = nextAppState;
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);
```

Update 3
So I tried to use Michael Bahl's solution as commented below. it works great with timestamp.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let start;
    let end;
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === "active"
      ) {
        end = new Date()
        let ms = moment(end).diff(moment(start))
        if (Number(ms) >= 30000) {
          dispatch(removeDataLogin())
        } else {
        }
      } else {
        start = new Date()
        console.log('start diff :', start)
      }
      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      console.log("AppState", appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

update 3 Im using Michael Bahl's solution so I created a timestamp that check the difference between inactive and active screens, then dispatch the redux action

```
useEffect(() => {
    let start;
    let end;
    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener("change", nextAppState => {
      if (
        appState.current.match(/inactive|background/) &&
        nextAppState === "active"
      ) {
        console.log('end =====')
        console.log('start diff == ', start)
        end = new Date()
        console.log('end diff ===', end)
        let ms = moment(end).diff(moment(start))
        console.log('different : ', ms)
        console.log(typeof ms)
        if (Number(ms) >= 30000) {
          console.log('harusnya logout')
          dispatch(removeDataLogin())
        } else {
          console.log(ms, 'masuk sini')
        }
      } else {
        start = new Date()
        console.log('start diff :', start)
      }


      appState.current = nextAppState;
      setAppStateVisible(appState.current);
      console.log("AppState", appState.current);
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: I would suggest do save a Timestamp when app went into background and when it comes back into foreground check if 30 seconds has been expired.
Depending whether the 30 seconds has been expired open login screen or keep latest opened screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle app state using [AppState](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate) and close it with [BackHandler](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler)

See example:

```jsx
import React, {useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {AppState, BackHandler} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const appState = useRef(AppState.currentState);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timeout;

    const subscription = AppState.addEventListener('change', (nextAppState) => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);

      if (appState.current === 'background') {
        timeout = setTimeout(() => BackHandler.exitApp(), 30000);
      }

      appState.current = nextAppState;
    });

    return () => {
      subscription.remove();
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);

  // TODO

  return /* TODO */;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, i've tried that but instead of using Backhandler. i dispatch an action like this , the thing is it is works fine but if the apps run on background for 10 sec and i open it again, the dispatch command will be executed after certain amount of time. is there any way to cancel the timeout when the app in foreground ?

Comment: update: the dispatch action still called in the foreground after 30 seconds is there any way to cancel the timeout?

Comment: @QrQr if you are targeting only **android**, then you can try [headless js](https://reactnative.dev/docs/headless-js-android), but if you need **both** platforms, you can try [native module](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-intro)